# Horizontal RecyclerView above Vertical RecyclerView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout that looks roughly like this:
[image: Horizontal RecyclerView on top of Vertical RecyclerView]

The entire pink area is a vertical `RecyclerView`. The bottom rectangle is a horizontal `RecyclerView`. These two views are both in a `RelativeLayout` where the horizontal `RecyclerView` is aligned to the bottom.

The issue I am having is this: when the horizontal `RecyclerView` does not have enough items to fill the width of the screen, I would like to be able to scroll the vertical `RecyclerView` behind it. So if you look at the green arrow in the image, I would like to scroll the vertical `RecyclerView` in that situation.

I have been unable to figure out how to get this working. I have tried setting up an `OnTouchListener` that returns false when an item in the horizontal `RecyclerView` is **NOT** touched. This doesn't seem to work though.

I have also tried setting the width of the horizontal `RecyclerView` to `WRAP_CONTENT` but the `RecyclerView` did not resize for some reason.

Is there anyway to just let the swipe pass through the horizontal `RecyclerView`? The horizontal `RecyclerView` has vertical scrolling disabled so I don't think it is even doing anything with the vertical scrolls, it is just absorbing them.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For API < 23. I tested following :

```
    final RecyclerView listA = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ListA);
    listA.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    listA.setAdapter(new CustomViewAdapter(100, R.layout.list_a_item)); //first parameter is item count

    final RecyclerView listB = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ListB);
    listB.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    listB.setAdapter(new CustomViewAdapter(4, R.layout.list_b_item)); // first parameter is item count

    listB.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            //get last child view of viewgroup.
            listB.getChildAt(listB.getChildCount()-1).getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
            //do not count margins
            r.offset(-listA.getLeft(), 0);
            if (event.getX() > r.right) {
                //Pass touch event directly to backround recycle view
                listA.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

RecycleView wrap_content should work as of API 23. You can set wrap_content so the view doesn't fill the screen up when there's not enough items.